# How to store session data using Owin hosting?

Tags: c#, session, owin, middleware, httpcontext

I have problem with creating a session in application hosted using Owin. I have tried using `RedisSession`, but I didn't know how to configure it so it gave me an error.
I was looking for a solution for some time, tried different things and finally decided to ask here for help.

### Scenario:

- I'm logging in the application using HTTP POST request,
- User login and password should be stored in session,
- For each next GET/POST request which need previous login session is
  empty (login and password are null).

Object `HTTPContext` is empty.

I'm using Ninject for dependency injections.

I tried something like that: [Can OWIN middleware use the http session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565543/can-owin-middleware-use-the-http-session)

**Does anybody have an idea how to store login data in Owin session?**

Below is Owin configuration file, included in it things are from link posted above.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Service.Startup))]
namespace Service
{
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            appBuilder.RequireAspNetSession();
            appBuilder.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel).UseNinjectWebApi(config);

        }

        public static StandardKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Module());
            return kernel;
        }
    }
    public static class AspNetSessionExtensions
    {
        public static IAppBuilder RequireAspNetSession(this IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                // Depending on the handler the request gets mapped to, session might not be enabled. Force it on.
                HttpContextBase httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
                httpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
                return next();
            });
            // SetSessionStateBehavior must be called before AcquireState
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar problem, if you had fingered out, plz share thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone wanting to do this with ASP.net Framework, instead of Core, read on.**

First, make sure `Owin.Extensions` is installed.

Next, add this code to your Owin `Startup.cs` *before* the middleware that you want to use session.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
    httpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
    return next();
}).UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
```

By default, OWIN Middleware run at the last event (PipelineStage.PreHandlerExecute) which is too late for accessing session state.

`.UseStageMarker` tells OWIN where in the execution pipeline to execute the function passed to `.Use()`.

To use sessions, you need to execute middleware that runs *after* the session has been initialized by the ASP.net runtime. This middleware must be run in the `PostAquireState` phase, like so:

```
.Use((context, next) =>
 {
     HttpContext.Current.Session["mykey"] = "myvalue";

     return next();
}).UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAcquireState);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some struggling with sessions as well.

Here is the solution, which works for me:

1) Add NuGet **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session**

2) Call **.AddSession** on your **IServiceCollection**. Note, it might need configuration.
In my case it is:
[image]

3) Use your session. Keep in mind, that if there are no values set to a session, on each request SessionID is different.
So you'd have to add some value to a session. This is how it would stay the same across multiple requests.

And here is my session pinning middleware:
[image]

Hope it helps.