# HttpContext.Current.Session is null + OWIN

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, owin

I'm entirely new to OWIN and this issue has been a major blocker for me.

Basically, at my MVC app I have the following at Startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = OfficeSettings.ClientId,
                    Authority = OfficeSettings.Authority,

                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        RoleClaimType = "roles"
                    },

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {

                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                        // code hidden for readability

                            if(HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
                            {
                                // It's null. Why is that?
                            }

                            var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
                            if (session["myMockSession"] != null)
                            {
                                // Do stuff...
                            }
                        },

                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                        {
                            // code hidden for readability
                        },

                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            // code hidden for readability
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I don't understand why when I'm debugging that the Session is null. HttpContext.Current Property isn't. Are there any constraints with Sessions + OWIN? Is there any workaround for this issue? How should one approach it?

Side note 1:
I've tried to add this piece of code I've found in one of the SO questions and the Session was still null:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                // Depending on the handler the request gets mapped to, session might not be enabled. Force it on.
                HttpContextBase httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
                httpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
                return next();
            });
```

Side note 2:
I don't seem to find it anymore, but someone suggested in one of the SO questions to add empty methods Session_Start and Session_End (as empty methods) at the Global.asax. That didn't worked neither.

I'm welcoming any advises.
Thanks!

Comment: I have similar issue. were you able to find some solution.

Comment: Hi @RonakThakkar. Unfortunately, not yet. I had to put this task aside because I couldn't find any solution. Perhaps we may get a solution in this thread, hopefully.

Comment: Hi AuroMetal, thank you for posting this question. I have been trying to get this to work, but I am not sure where to plugin the solution by @Johan O exactly. I would really appreciate if some one can provide more details.

Comment: Hi @AP, if I understood you correctly you are asking where to put this code? Bear in mind it's been over 2 years since the question, but I believe when you create a ASP.NET Web Application > MVC Template (Change Authentication - either Individual User || Work or School Account) an App_Start directory is created and under it there's a Startup.Auth.cs and there it's where you plugin the solution. Again, it's been so long that I may be wrong, so apologies in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're **almost** there. 
The reason your session is still null is that you have not instructed OWIN to initialize System.Web Sessions prior to your middleware is beeing executed.

By adding *.UseStageMarker(..)* **after** your middleware registration you'll tell OWIN where in the execution pipline it should perform *SetSessionStateBehaviour*

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
    httpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
    return next();
});

// To make sure the above `Use` is in the correct position:
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
```

By default, Owin Middleware run at the last event (PipelineStage.PreHandlerExecute) which is too late for you in this case.

Now, to use sessions, you need to work in a **second** middleware, that runs **after** the session has been Aquired by the Asp.Net runtime. This middleware must be run in the *PostAquireState* phase, like so:

```
.Use((context, next) =>
 {
     // now use the session
     HttpContext.Current.Session["test"] = 1;

     return next();
})
.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAcquireState);
```

Asp.Net katana docs has an [excellent article](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) on how the middleware works.
See the [PiplineStage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.pipelinestage(v=vs.113).aspx) enum docs and the [HttpApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) docs for details on the execution order in Asp.net.

Comment: Hi @Johan O, absolutely fantastic explanation! Thank you very much for the details, hopefully that will help a few of us with the same issue.

Comment: Your solution works but fails for `OpenIdConnectAuthentication`. I replaced your second snippet with `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(..., Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications { RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => { Console.WriteLine(HttpContext.Current.Session["test"]); } }); appUseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAcquireState);` but I get a null session in my `RedirectToIdentityProvider()` callback function.