# Microsoft SSO OpenID - Force a signout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, openid-connect, idp

Currently upgrading a legacy MVC.NET v3 application to v5 while changing over from Forms Authentication to Microsoft's SSO solution.  The requirement we would like to carry over is to force a logout if the user is idle for 30 minutes much like a banking application does due to the confidential information displayed within the application.  We've implemented this successfully in the legacy application but I'm having trouble with the signout mechanism.

```
public void SignOut()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

Without changing a thing when a user clicks the signout button - it'll redirect them to Microsoft's account selector to choose which account to log out - even if there's only one choice.  But if the user clicks the back button then they are back in the application which lets an authorized user see confidential information.  I need to force a logout on the current account to prevent that but I'm not able to figure out how.

I tried:

1. Clearing cookies.  Failed because if the bad actor clicks login again the current session remembers him and automatically logs them back in.
2. Overwriting the HttpContext.User - looks like it works.  But again clicking on login will automatically refresh the old session because the Token Provider remembers the state.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link to allow session variables with OWIN:
[Can OWIN middleware use the http session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565543/can-owin-middleware-use-the-http-session)

You'll need to review this link to allow system web cookies working with OWIN:
[ASP.NET_SessionId + OWIN Cookies do not send to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser)

I created another method that signs the user out and creates a session variable.

```
public void ForceSignOut()
{
    SignOut();

    HttpContext.Session.Add("IsSignoutRequested", true);
}
```

If the user clicks the back button and comes back to the application, I force redirect them back into a challenge.

In my startup class I have set the `PostLogoutRedirectUri` which lets me create another method on a successful logout which abandons the session.

```
public ActionResult CompleteSignOut()
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        controller = "User",
        action = "Index"
    }));
}
```